# Eigenvalues of a 3x3 Block Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $M$ to be a real and symmetric block matrix as
$$
M=
\begin{bmatrix}
\Lambda_{e\times e} & -I_{e\times e} & B_{e\times n}\\ 
-I_{e\times e} & \Lambda_{e\times e} & -B_{e\times n}\\
B^T & -B^T & \Gamma_{n\times n}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Where $\Lambda$ is a fully diagonal matrix with strictly positive entries and $\Gamma$ is another fully diagonal matrix with non-negative entries. What can we say about eigenvalues (or spectral radius) of $M$? Both $BB^T$ and $B^TB$ are positive semi-definite.

Thanks,